# bar chart in php,jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i want to make bar chart,but i want to write dynamic text on bar itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+bar+chart << did you do a search before you posted that ?

Comment: Google Provides Awesome Bar Chart Library. We followed https://www.studytutorial.in/multi-series-bar-chart-in-php-codeigniter-using-google-api-tutorial  in this tutorial we can get dynamic data from mysql and Plot dynamic Bar chart

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specifically `jQuery`, but I found this graphics toolkit rather simple to use, as you can learn by example, and they have many examples to peruse.

I recommend `Protovis` for creating charts with JavaScript. See their home page at: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

Answer (score 1):

Google Provides Awesome Bar Chart Library. We followed [Bar Chart tutorial](https://www.studytutorial.in/multi-series-bar-chart-in-php-codeigniter-using-google-api-tutorial) in this tutorial we can get dynamic data from mysql and Plot dynamic Bar chart

Answer (score 0):

[jQchart](http://jsgt.org/lib/jquery/plugin/jqchart/sample/v003/test-use-gradient.html)

[tufteGraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/)

[drillDown](http://kiersimmons.com/DDChart/index.html)

[google Charts](http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a small [graphing library](http://www.binpress.com/app/analytics-and-graphing-with-php-sql/851) for fetching database data, process it with PHP and create Google Analytics style interactive graphs from it (uses [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to render the graphs on the client side).

It's basically a complete server/client solution to turning your database tables into graphs, and should be easy to integrate with Kohana (I've used it a lot with the Zend Framework).